# How do I stop the music from playing?

Tags: java, netbeans

I have a button which when clicked plays the song but it doesnt stop and also I cant press any other button until the music stops on its own,i.e. the song gets over. Please help!
My code is as follows:

```
public class Mp3Player {

    private String filename;
    private Player player;


    public Mp3Player(String filename) {
    this.filename = filename;
    }


    public void play() {
 try {  

         BufferedInputStream buffer = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename));
         player = new Player(buffer);
         player.play();

 }
 catch (FileNotFoundException | JavaLayerException e) {

     System.out.println(e);
 }

    }


    }
```

And this is in the button:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

         Mp3Player mp3 = new Mp3Player("C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\Echo.mp3");
         mp3.play();

    }
```

Comment: I would suggest reading about threads.. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Answer (score 0):

Call Player#play on another thread, this will allow your song to play while allowing your GUI to still work (a common approach in Swing).

Once it's running on it's own thread, you can kill that thread to stop it, there are a lot of different ways to do this...which I'll leave for homework =)

Answer (score 0):

Create a [thread](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_multithreading.htm) to play the song without pausing the whole program.

<sup>PS. I would have written this as a comment but I don't have enough reputation points.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You are executing a blocking call (`Player::play`) in the event dispatcher thread, which means that you are blocking the processing of events (buttons clicked &co.) until `player.play()` returns.

Instead, call it in woker thread. First define a [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html):

```
class PlayerWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {
    private final Mp3Player mp3;

    public PlayerWorker(String filename) { 
         mp3 = new Mp3Player(filename);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() {
         mp3.play();
         return null;
    }
}
```

please mind the use of `Void` (capital `V`) and `return null`. Then, call it like:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
     (new PlayerWorker("C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\Echo.mp3")).execute();
}
```